# File not found at path: my_path/storage/file_39.pdf

Tags: laravel

I already made php artisan storage:link but this doesn't help.

```
public function downloadFile() { 
Storage::download(public_path(Storage::url('attachedFiles/user/2/ticket/39/file_39.pdf')));

}
```

ERROR:File not found at path: Users/aviageneration/Work/Small/feedback-service/public/storage/file_39.pdf

Comment: What is your actual file path from the laravel root?

Comment: @sta do you mean my public_path()?

Comment: Where the file `file_39.pdf` located from root?

Comment: @sta Oh sorry,I edited my path to this project_name/public/storage/attachedFiles/user/2/ticket/39/file_39.pdf

Comment: Your real need to be here `project_name/storage/app/public/attachedFiles/user/2/ticket/39/file_39.pdf` then you can access with `127.0.0.1:8000/storage/attachedFiles/user/2/ticket/39/file_39.pdf`

Comment: @sta I access here 127.0.0.1:8000/storage/attachedFiles/user/2/ticket/39/file_39.pdf and I successfully get my file. But what path I should write inside download method?

Comment: My answer didn't work?

Comment: @sta Sorry for late reply and thank you for your answer! This solution would be great for other case, but I used response()->download($file, $filename, $headers) and it worked for me. I couldn't figure out how to convert data from file_get_contents() so it would be downloadable for ajax blob. I can show code later if you want.

Comment: @sta It would great also try file_get_contents() way for downloading file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to download file. Instead of using Storage class I used response()->download():

```
$db_file_path = DB::table('tickets')
   ->select('file_path')
   ->where('id', $ticket_id)
   ->where('user_id', $user_id)
   ->first();
        
$fileName = 'file_'.$ticket_id.'.docx';    
$filePath = public_path('/storage/'.$db_file_path->file_path.'/'.$fileName);
$headers = array(
   'Content-Type: application/docx'
);
return response()->download($filePath, $fileName, $headers);
```